# Apache Camel - Exception - How caught an a exception

Tags: apache-camel

i'm newbie with apache camel (I'm using 2.8.1 version). I'm working with this framework and i understand (i hope) concept like route. Now i have this route definition

```
    try {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                from("vm:internal").
                split().method(DefaultSplitLogic.class, "split").
                dynamicRouter(bean(router, "route"));
            }
        });
    }catch (DefaultSplitLogicException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the DefaultSpliLogic.class

public class DefaultSplitLogic {

```
public Object[] split(Object o) throws DefaultSplitLogicException{
    if(o instanceof Collection<?>){
        Collection c = (Collection) o;
        return c.toArray();
    }
    else {
        throw new DefaultSplitLogicException("Default Splitting Logic not correct");    
    }
}
```

}

This is DefaultSplitLogicException.class

public class DefaultSplitLogicException extends Exception{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public DefaultSplitLogicException(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(msg);
    System.err.println(msg);
}

public  DefaultSplitLogicException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}
```

}

I leaved router definition.

Now i want to capture my exception (i'm sure that my exception is thrown).

I'm using the onException clause into the route definition

```
    try {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                onException(DefaultSplitLogicException.class).handled(false);

                from("vm:internal").
                split().method(DefaultSplitLogic.class, "split").
                dynamicRouter(bean(router, "route"));
            }
        });
    }catch (DefaultSplitLogicException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i cannot manage my exception. I tried to use differently this clause without success. Why?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the answer. It should be a bug of 2.8.1. version, fixed with 2.8.2+

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Cannot-handle-Exception-thrown-from-Splitter-Expression-td3286043.html